# Firebase Customize Authentication Domain Error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

I asked before but no one answer me and im still getting error. So I'm asking again;

Im trying to change my default domain address in Authentication templates such as Email verification send or password reset.

I got values from customize domain button you can see from this image[image: Customize domain button]

and then I got some DNS values(you can see these values in a crossed out) [image: my DNS values] to verify domain which I entered, is mine or not. Then I added these values to my DNS records from my DNS provider.

I'm probably making a mistake, but I don't understand what kind of mistake im doing. Because im still getting this error.

[image]

Comment: where are you hosting your domain, namecheap?

Comment: Im using Google Domains for hosting my domain but I solved my problem, it has nothing to do with my hosting company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my problem was while entering the dns settings and learned that I had to fill the host name blank. My problem was solved when I fill the host name blank and made my DNS settings.